# HttpPost encoding to windows-1255 add 25 to each char

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient

I tried to send data to server with httpPost.
its look like this:

```
String username = URLEncoder.encode("myUsername","windows-1255");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("****");
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

But it's sending to the server char as %25XX and not %XX.
Why it's happening?

Comment: it's %. more bla bla bla

Comment: That is not an answer. Every %## stands for an url encoded character. Please find out. Please tell exactly the string you sent and the string you received.

Comment: I meant that % is %25 after decoding

Comment: Do not first encode username as all will be encoded with new UrlEncodedFormEntity().

Comment: I need do to this, because I send it as charset windows-1255.anyway I found a solution.Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I was need to add the entity as string and not as list:

```
String param="username"+username;
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(param));
```